# button dropdown list-item type="submit"

Tags: html, css, django

I am working on a django application and have a form inside my page.

I have one action called "move" (next to delete, archive...) and based on the value that is given ( an ID) the right ID is passed through to my application:

HTML (bootstrap):

```
<button class="SelectionAction" type="submit" name="move" value="id1">Move to id1</button>
<button class="SelectionAction" type="submit" name="move" value="id2">Move to id2</button>
<button class="SelectionAction" type="submit" name="move" value="id3">Move to id3</button>
```

views.py:

```
tag_selection_form = TagSelectionForm(request.POST or None)
if tag_selection_form.is_valid():
    if 'move' in request.POST:
        new_tag_id = request.POST['move']
        new_tag_list = Tag.objects.get(user = request.user, id = new_tag_id)
        for item in tag_selection_form.cleaned_data['my_object']:
            item.tag_list.remove(tag_list)
            item.tag_list.add(new_tag_list)
    if 'delete' in request.POST:
        ...
    if 'archive' in request.POST:
        ...
    ...
```

My Problem:

I want to "stack" all the individual move buttons underneath one foldable (dropdown) button, something like this.

The dropdown on its own works, but I can not add `type="submit"` to an `<li><a>something</a></li>`  and placing `<button></button>` inside the `<li></li>` messes up the css.

```
<div class="dropdown div-inline SelectionAction">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Example
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><button class="SelectionAction" type="submit" name="move" value="id1">Move</button></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What is the best way forward for this matter?

Comment: What happens if you do `<input class="SelectionAction" type="submit" name="move" value="id1" />`? Instead of button.

Comment: with `<input value="id1"></input>` you get the same like `<button ... >id1</button>`. So the visible button text is what is inside the value field off the `<input></input>`-id...

Comment: What do you mean by "messes up the css"?

Comment: What if you used jQuery and ajax on the link upon clicking instead of a submit?

Comment: messed up meaning: a floating button in the <li> element, the jquery/ajax might indeed be the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ended up changing my own css of the buttons in that particular case so that it matched my layout of the dropdown field

```
.btn-dropdown {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.btn-dropdown:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```